# How to style list option in Autocomplete material ui with use of renderOption?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I am trying hard to customize option elements in autocomplete list. I want to do this by use of renderOptions prop, where i can create DOM elements. Then, i can pretty easly add styles with sx or styled components.

But something is wrong. When i try to render options list elements wrapped in divs, the names of the movies are hidden (?)
They are rendered, because i can still choose option, and after that it is showned as selected, but the input list is still broken, and CSS styles are not applied.

What I am missing ? Autocomplete and its styling is new for me.

The code:

```
<Autocomplete
        freeSolo
        id="free-solo-2-demo"
        disableClearable
        options={top100Films.map((option) => option.title)}
        renderOption={(props, option) => {
          return (
            <li {...props}>
              <div
                sx={{
                  backgroundColor: "red",
                  color: "orange"
                }}
              >
                {option.title}
              </div>
            </li>
          );
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label="Search input"
            InputProps={{
              ...params.InputProps,
              type: "search"
            }}
          />
        )}
      />
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

Heres the demo :  https://codesandbox.io/s/freesolo-material-demo-forked-dupxol?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** Just change `option.title` to `option` in `renderOption` prop. And use `Box` instead of `div` to apply styles.

I couldn't find it stated in documentation explicitly but apparently each of the elements passed to `options` is then passed to `renderOption` as `option` argument.

So since you already pass array of `option.title` strings to `options` you will need to refer to them just as `option` in `renderOption` prop.

The `sx` prop is used by MUI components. So please change `div` to MUI `Box` component inside `renderOption`. The `Box` was created specifically [for such cases](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-box/#the-sx-prop).

Comment: Yep, but styles are still not applied, sadly. Wonder why.

Comment: The `sx` prop is used by MUI components. So please change `div` to MUI `Box` component inside `renderOption`. The `Box` was created specifically [for such cases](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-box/#the-sx-prop)